# Openshift "no listening sockets available", how to change binding port?

Tags: python-2.7, openshift

I have two python applications on my openshift account.  Today one application doesn't load, and gives the response

> "Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address
>   127.11.204.1:8080 no listening sockets available, shutting down"

I've tried force stopping both applications and then restarting one, but this still hasn't resolved the issue.  How do I change the port which one of the applications tries to bind to from 8080 to a free port?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the cartridge you're using and how you deployed your application? Also be sure to check out this article that goes over environment variable usage which is critical for using the correct ports and hostnames https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being an openshift platform error, I checked the IRC messages and many others were also having the same problem.  Resolved now.
http://irc.lc/freenode/openshift